# How to make a select statement return null if no value is returned?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say we have the table "letters" like so:

```
a | b  
-----  
0 | 0  
0 | 1  
1 | 0  
1 | 1
```

And the following select statement:

```
SELECT val1, val2, x.a. val3
  FROM table1, 
       table2, 
       (SELECT a 
          FROM letters 
         WHERE a=b 
           AND a=0) x, 
       table3
 WHERE table1.val1 = table2.val1
   AND table1.val2 = table3.val3
```

I need the embeded SELECT statement (x) to return:

```
0  
NULL  
NULL  
NULL
```

Instead of what is currently returning which is

```
0
```

Then I want to be able to use that in the big SELECT statement.
I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Your query makes no sense, with respect to your question.  Apart from the poor formatting, it mentions three tables, `table1`, `table2`, and `letters`.  Your question only mentions one table.  Fix the question.  It might also help if you explain what you are trying to do, because there are no doubt better queries.

Comment: All that matters is that I get the result for the embedded select statement. I put the rest of the query there just to show that I need the result for yet another select. SELECT val1, val2, x.a. val3, will return nothing if x.a doesn't exist. I could post my exact querry but it's pretty complicated.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what exactly you're after, but if you don't want non-matching results to show from your sub-select, why not move it to a `JOIN`?

Comment: Could you write an example of how that would work in the presented case?

Comment: Are you intentionally looking for a cross join between subquery X and the joins on tables 1, 2 and 3?  If so subquery X should be defined as @dash inidicated by using the CASE statement instead of a where clause.  You might consider reordering the from list such that subquery X is last (after table3 instead of before), and rewriting the query using ANSI Join syntax to make your intent more explicit: from table1 join table2 on table1.val1 = table2.val2 join table3 on table1.val2 = table3.val2 cross join (subquery) x.

Answer (score 5):

There's a couple of ways you can go about this;

Trivial, using the [CASE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php) statement;

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN a = b AND a = 0 THEN a
        ELSE NULL
    END
FROM x
```

Returns:

```
0
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Using a [LEFT JOIN](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj18922.html):

```
SELECT  X1.a
FROM    x 
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT a, b FROM x WHERE a = b AND a = 0) AS X1 ON x.a = X1.a AND x.b = X1.b
```

Returns:

```
0
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause acts as a filter defining which rows are returned, but what you are asking is to have all rows returned, and apply a function on the returned rows to define the values returned for each row.

```
SELECT table1.val1
     , table1.val2
     , x.a
     , table3.val3
  FROM table1
  JOIN table2
    on table1.val1 = table2.val1
  JOIN table3
    on table1.val2 = table3.val3
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT CASE WHEN a = b AND a = 0 THEN a END AS a
               FROM letters) x
```

Answer (score 0):

going off of Dash's comment:

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN a = 1 OR b = 1 THEN Null
    ELSE 0
END
FROM x
```

as this would catch your second situation of b = 1, a = 0 and wanting a return of NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, if you're using a `GROUP BY` clause and you want to conditionally replace values with `NULL` based on some condition, you might need to use a subquery in your `FROM` clause

Answer (score -3):

If you want more than one column returned in the inner select, you'd need to specify those columns in the inner select as well...

```
(SELECT a, NULL 'colname1', NULL 'colname2'
          FROM letters 
         WHERE a=b 
           AND a=0) x,
```

You can access those columns using x.colname

If the columns could also have values besides NULL, you just need to add the proper joins and return the column values as a normal select statement would.